# Can't update database row according to specific user

Tags: php, mysqli

In my database I have my users who each have their own amount of "gold", I have made a button that increases the amount of gold they have by 100 for each click on it. The problem is, I can't figure out how to do it for a specific logged in user. Here's my current update code

```
$addgold2 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.gold = stats.gold + 100 WHERE stats.id=$retval2");
```

If I remove "$retval2" and input just the ID, it works. I want to call the ID for the logged in user and then update just those stats. Here's the code I have for it

```
$id2 = "SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.username=$username";
$retval2 = mysqli_query($con,$id2);
```

Now, if I echo $id2, it shows the ID is "1", but it isn't 1! it's 7 :(

I also get this error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in    C:\wamp\www\Game\addgold.php on line 19
```

On the first line of code I've put

And finally, here's the entire code (form is on a different page)

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
include("connect.php");
include("header.php");
$username = $_SESSION['userlogin'];
$id2 = "SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.username=$username";
$retval2 = mysqli_query($con,$id2);
$sql = "SELECT stats.id, stats.gold, users.id, users.username FROM stats, users WHERE users.username     = '$username' AND stats.id = users.id";
$retval = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Gold: {$row['gold']}  <br> ".

         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($retval2); 
$id2 = mysqli_num_rows($retval2) or die(mysql_error()." ".$id2);
echo $id2;
if(isset($_SESSION['userlogin'])){ 
$addgold2 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.gold = stats.gold + 100 WHERE     stats.id=$retval2");
if(isset($addgold2['submit'])){

}

echo "You have earned 100 gold!";
mysqli_close($con);


}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the single quote in your `$id2` sql

```
$id2 = "SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.username='$username'";
```

Comment: I didn't think it mattered but tried it anyway and didn't work :( still showing incorrect ID

Comment: Yeah, didn't make a difference unfortunately. I think Bobby Stenly's answer will help, so trying that atm

Comment: but you still should add the single quotes, because field type of `username` is `varchar`

Comment: I've figured it out sorta, not sure if adding the quotes helped lol. $row2["id"] returns the id but it gives an error message when I put it in the addgold2 query, do you have to put it a certain way?

Comment: you don't need this line `$id2 = mysqli_num_rows($retval2) or die(mysql_error()." ".$id2);`, so replace it to `$id2 = $row2["id"];`, then replace your update sql as `"UPDATE stats SET stats.gold = stats.gold + 100 WHERE stats.id=$id2");`

Comment: Yes! it works!! :) wish I could choose two answers, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

$retval2 on your 19th line is not an ID that you're looking for.

```
$id2 = mysqli_num_rows($retval2) or die(mysql_error()." ".$id2);
```

it will return 1 if it has 1 row.. not the ID

```
$addgold2 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.gold = stats.gold + 100 WHERE     stats.id=$retval2");
```

The $retval2 is mysqli_query result, and thats not ID
I think $row2["id"] is your ID.

Comment: Don't know how I didn't realise that lol I'm trying to echo row2 now "$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($retval2); ", but now get "Notice: Array to string conversion" -,-

Comment: Changed to "$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($retval2, MYSQL_ASSOC); " but still the same, thought that would sort it

Comment: Sorry but I got the echo working!! "echo $row2["id"];", but how do I display that id in an update query?

Comment: worldask answered my remaining queries